# error: unable to find container in kubectl set image

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubectl

I am trying to push an update to my codebase for my docker image. I have the docker image on kubernetes on GCP and I followed the way it was mentioned in the document [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/hello-app).
I even pushed the image with :v2 tag to the container registry and that image is visible in the console as well. But now when I am trying to run:

```
kubectl set image deployment/clustername myImageName=gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/myImageName:v2
```

it gives me the following error:

```
error: unable to find container myImageName
```

I know that the image is there because I build it with

```
docker build -t gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/myImageName:v2 .
```

I have also fixed the issue of: `Error from server (NotFound): deployments.extensions` 
I am stuck at this very moment. Can anyone throw some light on it?

Comment: Hi, check the name of container in the podSpec.

Comment: Where can i find the podSpec? Any clue?

Comment: `kubectl get deployment clustername -o yaml` will get you the spec

Comment: Hey, Thanks! I got it working but seems like there was no change being made. But I guess I got this issue resolved at least. I don't know why but the container had sha26 added to it's name, maybe I missed it

Comment: When I updated the image the way you said, the command showed me that the image is updated but what happened after it is that it fell under crashloopbackoff error. Now I am confused whether it happened because of my codebase or I need to restart the cluster?

Comment: you can check the condition part of the status `kubectl get pod $pod_name -o yaml` you do not need to start the cluster

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199734/discussion-between-suresh-vishnoi-and-siddharth-choudhary).

Answer (score 10):

The error message specifies that your deployment doesn't have a container named `myImageName`.

The syntax for `kubectl set image` is:

```
kubectl set image deployment-name container-name=image-name
```

`container-name` must be the name of a container you specified inside your deployment under `spec.template.spec.containers.name`.

Answer (score 5):

check 'myImageName' container name is matching in the pod description.

Try command : `kubectl describe pods`

In pod description check the following under 'Containers' section: In the below example 'avroconsumerclient' is the name of the container.

```
Containers:
  avroconsumerclient:
    Container ID:   docker://ab5890be34dfk5678dfdf5670ac19583d8859427695a258d4fdfd
    Image:          ************/democlient:v2
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://********/democlient@sha256:71e97df533915d62c433c2c04168bb7b1dd545c7ef423169a1452ac5abd4302e
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Running
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation on the GCP hello-app tutorial has the syntax wrong. It should be:

```
kubectl set image deployment/clustername 
clustername=gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/myImageName:v2
```

rather than:

```
kubectl set image deployment/clustername 
myImageName=gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/myImageName:v2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your command is wrong you have to remove the `myImageName` before the image url and pass the command

```
kubectl set image <deployment name> gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/myImageName:v2
```

Comment: Wait According to the document I can see the command is like the way @Alassane Ndiaye has mentioned. Are you sure about it?

Comment: @SiddharthChoudhary you can give a try as test.